# jQuery unbind then bind

Tags: jquery, click, bind, unbind

I'm unbinding click from these clickable divs and then want to enable clicking again. What I have doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
    $('#a, #b, #c').on('click', function(e){
        $('#a, #b, #c').unbind('click');
        // some stuff
        // bind again: 
        // this doesn't work: $('#a, #b, #c').bind('click');
    }
```

Comment: Also, suggestions for hover (unbind hover then bind later). Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just `toggleClass` and check for said class existance?

Comment: missed function in `bind click`?

Comment: Instead of `bind/unbind` try using a `flag` inside click and `return false` further clicks until your `//some stuff` is complete

Comment: @Vega I thought of adding flag or toggling it but there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: @ialphan I think the flag is much better than event registration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the handler function `// this doesn't work: $('#a, #b, #c').bind('click');` when you try to rebind.. what you need is something like below,

```
$('#a, #b, #c').bind('click', clickHandlerA);

function clickHandlerA() {
   $('#a, #b, #c').unbind('click');
   // some stuff
   // bind again: 
   // this should work: 
   $('#a, #b, #c').bind('click', clickHandlerA);
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to be more specific with the unbind and do: $('#a, #b, #c').unbind('click', clickHandlerA); This way your are sure you are just unbinding what interests you.

Answer (score 1):

to "unbind" on u need to use ".off"  http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
$('#a, #b, #c').on('click', function(e){
    $('#a, #b, #c').off('click');
    // some stuff
    // bind again: 
    // this doesn't work: $('#a, #b, #c').bind('click');
}
```

Comment: .off is more proper way to do then .unbind but this doesn't resolve my issue. I need to bind it. Thanks.